# .only().prefetch_related() gives 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: python, django

i am fetching required fields of a table after a select_related() and prefetch_related() on the same query using .only()

I can't seem to get the result from prefetch_related probably because .only() is restricting access to its result ?

I have tried adding prefetch_related field in .only() as well but to no avail.

```py
Feedback.objects.all().select_related(
            'feedback_option'
        ).only(
            'feedback_option',

            # tried with and without either one or both of the following
            'feedback__remarks',
            'feedback__remarks__text'
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'feedback__remarks',
                queryset=FeedbackRemark.objects.all().only('text'),
            ),
        )
```

I am getting the following exception because of this.

AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'

I am using django 1.10.5

Comment: Got any solutions?

Comment: I think this is a bug

Comment: I think what worked for me was ignoring "select_related" and "prefetch_related" altogether and using .only() alone which was far more better than prefetching or using "select_related". But i guess, if you need to customize your query using prefetch_related, than the issue still exists.

Comment: For me, the error persists even after removal of `only` from queryset

Comment: After some experiments in similar case, I figured out that removing prefetched field from .only() statement will fix an error.

Comment: @bilbohhh also, prefetch broke and makes additional requests per model

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, solved it by replacing .only() with .defer(), listing all unused fields.
This shorten the memory used, at no additional db queries.